# Bcrypt compareSync is always returning False

Tags: node.js

trying the user Auth first time and able to create the users, it seems the bcrypt password hash is working when registering the user as I can see the hashed password in the DB, However when I am trying to login with the same credential, getting an error Invalid email or password based on my code below:

```
const {
    create,
    getUserByUserId,
    getUserByUserEmail,
} = require('./user-services')

const {genSaltSync, hashSync, compareSync} = require('bcrypt')
const {sign} = require('jsonwebtoken')

module.exports = {
    createUser: (req, res) => {
      const body = req.body;
      const salt = genSaltSync(10);
      body.password = hashSync(body.password, salt);
      create(body, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return res.status(500).json({
            success: 0,
            message: "Database connection errror"
          });
        }
        return res.status(200).json({
          success: 1,
          data: results
        });
      });
    },
    login: (req, res) => {
        const body = req.body;
        console.log(body.user_email)
        getUserByUserEmail(body.user_email, (err, results) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
          if (!results) {
            return res.json({
              success: 0,
              data: "* Invalid email or password *"
            });
          }
          const result = compareSync(body.password, results.password);
          console.log(result)
          console.log(results.password)
          console.log(body.password)
          if (result) {
            results.password = undefined;
            const jsontoken = sign({ result: results }, "test1234", {
              expiresIn: "1h"
            });
            return res.json({
              success: 1,
              message: "Login successfully",
              token: jsontoken
            });
          } else {
            return res.json({
              success: 0,
              data: "Invalid email or password"
            });
          }
        });
      },
}
```

When console log, I can see the body. password and response from DB. Here is what I am getting in the console.log

[image]

[image]

Comment: post here the results that your app shows, in order to understand in a better way.

Comment: @YuriMelo posted a screenshot for the console log

Comment: inside `getUserByUserEmail` function, right after error if statement, show us the result variable. Put a `console.log(result);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Solved it. Modified MySQL column for Password to VARCHAR(1024). it was
> limited to VARCHAR(56)